# WordPress using deprecated mysql_connect no matter what I do

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, deprecated

Today I installed the latest version of WordPress and all went fine, except the fact that when I'm trying to config the database access. WordPress insists on using mysql_connect which is undefined in PHP versions above 5.X. I already tried setting wp-config by defining this:

```
define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', false);
```

also tried setting it as true just for testing purposes, and nothing works.

Also, I already set up all extensions in PHP including mysqlnd and mysqli. Basically I did everything in stackoverflow and still I got nothing.

The following error is what is showing up:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in

I'm using PHP 7.4 and MySQL 8.0. Also, WordPress is in its latest version.

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?

Answer (score 3):

In Wordpress's source code, the condition for deciding to use mysqli or mysql is the following in [wp-db.php:615](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8e08c569c512932b0802c70c3bf786483ddd10b5/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L615), the variable `$this->use_mysqli`:

```
if ( function_exists( 'mysqli_connect' ) ) {
    $this->use_mysqli = true;

    if ( defined( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL' ) ) {
        $this->use_mysqli = ! WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL;
    }
}
```

If the function `mysqli_connect` existed, you'd be okay as the later `if` statement which decides to use between `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_connect` is in function `db_connect()` in [wp-db.php:1630](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8e08c569c512932b0802c70c3bf786483ddd10b5/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1630), simplified below:

```
if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
  // [...]
  @mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
}else{
  // [...]
  $this->dbh = @mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
}
```

I would say that the reason is that you don't have mysqli installed, is that possible?

Can you make sure you have the proper packages installed. On a debian machine, I would have to install the php-mysql package, e.g.

```
apt install php-mysql
```